# not able to host wcf service even after adding mex binding

Tags: c#, wcf, localhost, hosting, iis-express

Please find my web configuration, I have added mex binding in my config file. yet getting error that the metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" 
        name="Launch.LaunchService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="Launch.ILaunchService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7777/LaunchService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
     multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in your config code,may be something to do with IIS.

Comment: I haven't used that binding anywhere in my service, but had added it... Anyways I have found the mistake. Needed to install aspnet_regiis through visual studio command prompt. Its working fine now. Thank you Hameed.